# Is it possible to include a ForeignKey inside a JSONField schema? How else can I effect this?

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

I am building an app in Django that allows users to build their own forms and in effect customise dynamic models.

After much research, I've decided to effect this through Django, PostgreSQL and JSONFields where one model holds the schema and another holds the record data:

```
class = Template(models.Model):
    schema = JSONField(null=True) # Schema for the form/model

class = DynamicModel(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(null=True) # Corresponding data for the form/model
    template =  models.ForeignKey(Template, null=True, 
                    blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

This means users can define their own model templates and I can hold different records using that template in another model.

The idea is to parse the `template.schema` JSONField to display editable forms using jQuery and to store the output as `dynamicmodel.data` JSONField. Validations are passed on the client side.

[image]

However, this comes with the drawback if I want to allow users to include `ForeignKey` lookups in their models. For example, say they wanted to add a choice box that offered selections from different `customer.id`s in a `Customer(models.Model)` class.

Without hardcoding the ForeignKey directly into the DynamicModel class (which would defeat the point of the exercise) can you think of a way I can achieve this?